# Vertical bar in Python bitwise assignment operator

Tags: python, python-2.7, operators

There is a code and in class' method there is a line:

```
object.attribute |= variable
```

I can't understand what it means. I didn't find (|=) in the list of basic Python operators.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

That is a `bitwise or` with assignment. It is equivalent to

```
object.attribute = object.attribute | variable
```

Read [more here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators).

Comment: Mostly equivalent - it might be done in-place, depending on the object.

Answer (score 17):

In python, `|` is short hand for calling the object's `__or__` method, as seen [here in the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__or__) and this code example:

```
class Object(object):
    def __or__(self, other):
        print("Using __or__")
```

Let's see what happens when use `|` operator with this generic object.

```
In [62]: o = Object()

In [63]: o | o
using __or__
```

As you can see the, the `__or__` method was called. `int`, 'set', 'bool' all have an implementation of `__or__`. For numbers and bools, it is a bitwise OR. For sets, it's a union.  So depending on the type of the attribute or variable, the behavior will be different. Many of the bitwise operators have set equivalents, [see more here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html#set-objects).

Answer (score 17):

I should add that "bar-equals" is now (in 2018) most popularly used as a set-union operator to append elements to a set if they're not there yet.

```
>>> a = {'a', 'b'}
>>> a
set(['a', 'b'])

>>> b = {'b', 'c'}
>>> b
set(['c', 'b'])

>>> a |= b
>>> a
set(['a', 'c', 'b'])
```

One use-case for this, say, in natural language processing, is to extract the combined alphabet of several languages:

```
alphabet |= {unigram for unigram in texts['en']}
alphabet |= {unigram for unigram in texts['de']}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

For an integer this would correspond to Python's "bitwise or" method. So in the below example we take the bitwise or of 4 and 1 to get 5 (or in binary 100 | 001 = 101):

```
Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 17 2016, 17:05:23) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
    >>> a = 4
    >>> bin(a)
    '0b100'
    >>> a |= 1
    >>> bin(a)
    '0b101'
    >>> a
    5
```

More generalised (as Alejandro says) is to call an object's **or** method, which can be defined for a class in the form:

```
def __or__(self, other):
    # your logic here
    pass
```

So in the specific case of an integer, we are calling the **or** method which resolves to a bitwise or, as defined by Python.