# What does this pipe operator mean in Python 3.x?

Tags: python, python-3.x, lambda, pipe

I am reading python code like below. But I can not understand `lambda x, y: x | y` mean. `(set(list(chain.from_iterable(s)) + q + a) for s, q, a in data))` looks complicated, but it is just a vocabulary list like `['to', 'the', 'who']`.

```
# ex) data[0]
#     ([[s1], [s2]], [q], [a]])
#     ([['mary', 'moved', 'to', 'the', 'bathroom'], ['john', 'went', 'to', 'the', 'hallway']], ['where', 'is', 'mary'], ['bathroom'])
vocab = sorted(reduce(lambda x, y: x | y, (set(list(chain.from_iterable(s)) + q + a) for s, q, a in data)))
```

https://github.com/domluna/memn2n/blob/master/single.py#L36

To be sure, I printed `x` and `y`. But I have no idea what these are. What do `x` and `x|y` mean?

```
reduce(lambda x, y: print(x, type(x), "---", y, type(y)), (set(list(chain.from_iterable(s)) + q + a) for s, q, a in data))
# None <class 'NoneType'> --- {'where', 'kitchen', 'bathroom', 'the', 'sandra', 'travelled', 'daniel', 'bedroom', 'back', 'went', 'journeyed', 'office', 'moved', 'hallway', 'garden', 'is', 'john', 'to'} <class 'set'>
```

Comment: it's redefined by `set` objects to perform unions.

Comment: read there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5988665/pipe-character-in-python

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38126100/2863154

Comment: you can probably perform the same thing without reduce.

Comment: Thank you guys. I thought pipe is only used for integer. `reduce` is similar to recursive function. `x` means previous result and `y` means current `set` result, right?

Comment: yes, applies on the "accumulated" result and so on.